# Converting self-releasing objects to ARC

Tags: macos, cocoa, design-patterns, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

OK, so Apple brought ARC to us, which is great. After refactoring my Application to ARC almost everything works fine and it is a lot easier now to develop and maintain.

There is just one problem I still can't figure out.

My job management program shows different detail information of proposals, orders and so on in their own windows. So I have a special class where WindowControllers gets allocated and initiated with initWithWindowNibName and then the window is shown with showWindow:

```
DetailWindowController *proposalWindowController = [[DetailWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ThePorposalWindow"];
[proposalWindowController showWindow:nil];
```

Before ARC the Instance of the WindowController did the release like shown in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingWindowController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000225-BAJCCIFJ):

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   [self autorelease];
}
```

But now with ARC this is not possible anymore and what makes it even worse, in my special class where the WindowController is allocated and initiated, the same windowController is released by ARC because there is no pointer to the windowController.

My idea was to copy the windowController into an mutuable array:

```
[proposalWindowArray addObject:proposalWindowController];
[[proposalWindowArray lastObject] showWindow:nil];
```

And in the windowControllers delegate method windowWillClose I post a notification to my special class:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ProposalWindowWillClose" object:[[self window] windowController] userInfo:nil];
}
```

In my special class I listen to the notification and remove the object from the array:

```
- (void) proposalWindowWasClosed: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    [proposalWindowArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:[notification object]];
}
```

It works, but I still do not believe that this is the correct way.

Does anybody has the same problem or a tip to make it better?

Comment: Your new method is basically correct. With ARC, you need to keep explicit references to objects in order for the compiler to be able to track the retain/release calls correctly. In fact, I think that you should avoid tricks like calling `release` in callback methods in general, whether or not you're using ARC.

Comment: @RobKeniger: What do you suggest instead? Imagine we’re in the app delegate which forwards received actions to view / window controllers and there are usually a lot of different controllers involved. Creating a property for each one seems to be unnecessary messy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd probably use a delegate approach rather than notifications. Generally it is better to have an external object that keeps track of the open windows. Self-retaining objects, like your old system, break the basic points of object ownership and make it hard to find things (such as "give me a list of open windows"). Non-Singletons that are just "floating" out there often come back to bite you in your architecture (I've had to fix this often enough).

That said, sometimes self-ownership is at least convenient, and at worst not-the-end-of-the-world. So self-own. The only difference is that you need to do it explicitly rather than matching a leak and an over-release (which is what your old code was doing).

Create a private `strong` property. Assign `self` to it. That will create a retain loop that will keep you around until you set the property to `nil`.

Comment: So your answer is to keep an array of window controller subclasses in your class that acts as the delegate and is called in the windowWillClose method of the window controller?

Comment: Depending on the system, I often just have a central `WindowManager` singleton and let it watch `NSWindowWillCloseNotification`, but sometimes I use delegation as you say. Depends on how integrated it needs to be. The WindowManager generally owns all the WindowControllers in the system. That's just the design I usually find I wind up with by the time I'm done.

Comment: Rob: After doing a lot of further research on this topic (espescially working through the "iPad and iPhone App Development" course from Paul Hegarty, found in iTunes U, which I can highly recomment) I accept your last answer. I did it now tihs way (watching the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification`) and it seems to be the most elegant and reasonable way. So thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Without hacks, there is no elegant way to keep an object retained other than having a strong reference to it in some other object. For example, you could keep a static `NSMutableArray`/`NSMutableSet`, add your controller there, and remove it in `windowsWillClose:`. This will be shorter than posting a notification. To make this reusable, create a `WindowControllerRegistry` singleton with an array, where you add controllers like this one, and which will automatically listen to `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` and remove them from its array thus releasing ownership.

As a quick workaround, you could perform `retain`/`autorelease` calls from [non-ARC file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project):

```
my_retain(self);
my_autorelease(self);

// ArcDisabled.mm
void my_retain(id obj) { [obj retain]; }
void my_autorelease(id obj) { [obj autorelease]; }
```

Comment: Thank you hamstergene, that will probably work. But I'm looking for a bit more elegant solution. There must be a solution without using retain and release. Otherwise I didn't have to switch to ARC.

Comment: ARC makes retain/release a compiler function. Calling them this way is undefined compiler behavior under ARC, and could do anything. It could leak, work, crash, sometimes or always. By spec, it could come and kick your dog. The compiler has optimizations that remove unnecessary retains and releases as it sees fit. ARC sometimes "fakes" retain and release. Your approach can unbalance the system depending on how the compiler optimizes. More on undefined behavior: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 More on ARC optimizations: http://bit.ly/friday-qa-2011-09-30

Comment: @RobNapier The trick is dirty and should not be used, but why do you think it has undefined behavior? ARC does not cancel dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Because the spec defines such a program as "ill-formed." See section 7.1.1 of the ARC spec. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#misc.special_methods.retain

Comment: @RobNapier Ill-formed != UB. It means it must not compile (and it won't if you try writing `@selector(retain)` in any ARC-enabled file, without even sending it), hence the use of selector-from-string hack. But it is not UB in actually invoking these methods dynamically or from non-ARC code of the same project.

Comment: You have tricked it into compiling by hiding the call from the compiler. But if the compiler eliminates or reorders a retain, you could overrelease here, since objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue may not determine correctly whats happen later when it introspects the stack return pointer (check mikeash's discussion of this). You could get away with it in several cases, and possibly even in all cases for this version of the compiler, but you are outside defined behavior within a compile unit compiled with ARC. In a non-ARC compile unit, the compiler is not allowed to optimize this way.

Comment: @RobNapier I still don't get how this particular use of  `performSelector` could possibly lead to overreleasing, but I see the danger of this trick in general. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your alternative approach should be correct, but I don't think you need the second notification. You should be able to do:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [proposalWindowArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:self];
}
```

Assuming the "proposalWindowArray" is a static NSMutableArray.

Comment: Unfortunately proposalWindowArray is a private property of my special class detailWindowController which manages the allocating and initializing of the windowControllers like proposalWindowController. So there is no way to gain access to the private property of detailWindowController out of proposalWindowController.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when I switched to ARC.  Your solution works, but you're making it too complicated.  You can essentially do what you were doing before by having the window release itself when it closes, but in an ARC compatible manner.

The solution is to simply create a property of your class within the class itself.  For your example, in DetailWindowController, you would add the following property:

```
@property (strong)  DetailWindowController      *theWindowController;
```

Then when you create the window with your code above, add one line like so:

```
DetailWindowController *proposalWindowController = [[DetailWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ThePorposalWindow"];
[preferenceController setTheWindowController:proposalWindowController];
[proposalWindowController showWindow:nil];
```

Then finally, to have ARC release the window when it is closed like you did with the autorelease pre-ARC, in the DetailWindowController class, simply do:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Let ARC tear this down and clean it up
    [self setTheWindowController:nil];
}
```